# Django modelformset_factory widget validation

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble understanding how form/model field validation works in Django 4.1.1.

I want to use the models.CharField in my model with the

```
stores = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length=255)
```

however when inputting and posting my formset no validation is carried out like it would be if I used models.EmailField and forms.EmailInput in the form/widget.

I'm probably not understanding something properly but can't for the life of me work it out. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction. Be as harsh as you like.

forms.py -

```
ServerFormSet = modelformset_factory(
RequestServersStores, fields=("server_number", "store_numbers"), extra=1, validate_max=True, validate_min=True,
labels={
    'server_number': 'Server Number',
    'store_numbers': 'Store Numbers'

},
widgets={
    'server_number': forms.Select(
        choices=server_choices
    ),
    'store_numbers': forms.TextInput(
        attrs={
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'comma separated list of store numbers e.g. 7,15,29'
        }
    )
})
```

views.py -

```
    ...
    elif request.method == 'POST':

    create_request = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
    server_formset = ServerFormSet(request.POST)
    if create_request.is_valid() and server_formset.is_valid():
        request = create_request.save()
        for form in server_formset:
            server = form.save(commit=False)
            server.request = request
            server.save()
```

models.py -

```
class RequestServersStores(models.Model):
objects = models.manager
server_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
store_numbers = models.CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list], max_length=255)
request = models.ForeignKey(
    CreateUserRequest,
    related_name='servers', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    null=True
)
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. But I think the issue is you are simply doing nothing if the form is not valid. Like you should have an else block after **if** to do something (show errors) for invalid forms.

Comment: Well the issue is that even if the data is wrong in the field the form still seems to be valid and the data is written to the db. If there was an else it wouldn't be hit in this case.